# Change WordPress Multisite Domain

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping, phpmyadmin

I created a multisite install on a development domain. Now, I want to change it over to my main domain. I've heard that I shouldn't do a database dump, and change everything with a text editor. I've followed the WPEngine tutorial below, but it caused 500 server errors. Any advice?

http://wpengine.com/support/how-to-change-a-multi-site-primary-domain/

Comment: Can you debug the 500 errors? Was there anything in your Apache error log (or equivalent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I move domains and have to change the domain in the database, I use [interconnectit's Search and Replace tool](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB). Here is a very brief overview of the process.

1. Export the database and upload it to the new server.
2. Upload [interconnectit's Search and Replace tool](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB) to the new server.
3. Configure what I want to be replaced in the databases with the tool's GUI
4. Click "run" and that's it.

You can find installation details and support over at the project's GitHub page.